# Using a variable for a field name in Json stringify

Tags: json

```
var payload =  JSON.stringify(
  {"Name__c" : data[i].name,
   "Email__c" : data[i].email
  }
);
```

How can I do the above one like below.

```
var nameVar = "Name__c";
var payload =  JSON.stringify(
  {nameVar : data[i].name,
   "Email__c" : data[i].email
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nameVar = "Name__c";

var item = {}
item [nameVar] = data[i].name;
item ["Email__c"] = data[i].email;

var payload = JSON.stringify(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
var nameVar = "Name__c";
var p = {"Email__c" : data[i].email};
p[nameVar] = data[i].name;
var payload =  JSON.stringify(p);
```